# Check if PEAR MAIL installed

Tags: php, pear

Pear is installed on my server. How to check PEAR MAIL is installed and how to find the right PATH to pear!

```
require_once 'System.php';
var_dump(class_exists('System'));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and managed to get this.

To check for installed packages, run

`pear list`

Here's the [pear link](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.packageinfo.php) for getting information about packages.

For finding the PEAR path, PEAR's php_dir should be in PHP's *include path*. If not, add it in your system's php.ini.

To check PHP's *include_path* in your web server, create a php file with only `phpinfo();` as the contents, and save it in your local web root as check_php.php. Open the file in your browser, to verify the include_path your web server is using.

Check [this pear link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php) for more information about verifying the include path

Comment: `pear list -a` to see all packages installed, not only from the default channel.

Answer (score 0):

I am describing below how I achieved it using the steps described at https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php.

1) Confirm that PEAR is installed.

```
root@web [/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear]# pear version
PEAR Version: 1.10.7
PHP Version: 7.0.33
Zend Engine Version: 3.0.0
Running on: Linux web.example.net 2.6.32-754.27.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 28 14:11:45 UTC 2020 x86_64
```

2) This is where PEAR installs `.php` files:

```
root@web [/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear]# pear config-get php_dir
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear
```

3) This is the content of the folder where PEAR installs `.php` files:

```
root@web [/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear]# ls -al
total 128
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Mar 30 15:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 Mar 11 10:17 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 Archive/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 Console/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 30 15:19 Mail/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9878 Mar 30 15:19 Mail.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 OS/
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 PEAR/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15220 Mar 23 14:13 pearcmd.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 35466 Mar 23 14:13 PEAR.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1069 Mar 23 14:13 peclcmd.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 Structures/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20562 Mar 23 14:13 System.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 25 15:02 XML/
```

4) I see `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear/Mail.php`, whose content starts with these lines:

```
root@web [/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear]# cat Mail.php
<?php
/**
 * PEAR's Mail:: interface.
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * LICENSE:
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1997-2017, Chuck Hagenbuch & Richard Heyes
 * All rights reserved.
```

5) In `/home/website/public_html/stagingarea/app/webroot/testemail.php` I created this script:

```
<?php
    require_once "/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear/Mail.php";
    $recipients = 'webmaster@jaimemontoya.com';
    $headers['From']    = 'webmaster@jaimemontoya.com';
    $headers['To']      = 'webmaster@jaimemontoya.com';
    $headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';
    $body = 'Test message';
    $params['sendmail_path'] = '/usr/lib/sendmail';
    // Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
    $mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);
    $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
?>
```

6) I visited https://www.example.net/stagingarea/testemail.php and that script sent the email successfully:

[image]